# Can't get ChainExtension's caller address right

Tags: substrate-contracts-node

I'm trying to build a ChainExtension, so that my pallet can deal with invocations from Ink! smart contracts. The problem is that I can't get the address right.

Here is that part of the chain extension code:

```
// Get the caller's address.
let who = env.ext().caller().account_id()?;

// Execute pallet logic.
<pallet_hackathon::Pallet<Runtime> as pallet_hackathon::traits::courses::Create<
  <Runtime as SysConfig>::AccountId,
  <Runtime as pallet_hackathon::Config>::CourseId,
  <Runtime as pallet_hackathon::Config>::NestedSkillsLimit,
  <Runtime as pallet_hackathon::Config>::StringLimit,
>>::create_course(
  who,
  course_id,
  open,
  required_skills,
  gained_skills,
  credential_description,
)?;
```

It results on the following error:

```
expected reference `&AccountId32`   found reference `&<<E as Ext>::T as SysConfig>::AccountId`consider constraining the associated type `<<E as Ext>::T as SysConfig>::AccountId` to `AccountId32`for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html
```

The trait I'm using is defined like this:

```
use crate::skill::{RequiredSkill, Skill};
use frame_support::sp_runtime::{BoundedVec, DispatchResult, TokenError};

// Trait for creating courses.
pub trait Create<AccountId: Eq, CourseId, NestedSkillsLimit, StringLimit> {
    fn create_course(
        _who: &AccountId,
        _course_id: CourseId,
        _open: bool,
        _required_skills: BoundedVec<RequiredSkill, NestedSkillsLimit>,
        _gained_skills: BoundedVec<Skill, NestedSkillsLimit>,
        _credential_description: BoundedVec<u8, StringLimit>,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        Err(TokenError::Unsupported.into())
    }
}
```

The implementation is defined like this:

```
use crate::{
    skill::{RequiredSkill, Skill},
    traits::courses::Create,
    Config, Pallet,
};
use frame_support::sp_runtime::{BoundedVec, DispatchResult};

impl<T: Config<I>, I: 'static>
    Create<
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        T::CourseId,
        T::NestedSkillsLimit,
        T::StringLimit,
    > for Pallet<T, I>
{
    fn create_course(
        who: &T::AccountId,
        course_id: T::CourseId,
        open: bool,
        required_skills: BoundedVec<RequiredSkill, T::NestedSkillsLimit>,
        gained_skills: BoundedVec<Skill, T::NestedSkillsLimit>,
        credential_description: BoundedVec<u8, T::StringLimit>,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        Self::do_create_course(
            who,
            course_id,
            open,
            required_skills,
            gained_skills,
            credential_description,
        )
    }
}
```

Perhaps it's good to mention that I also tried to invoke pallet functionality this way, since I found an example that does this:

```
let caller = env.ext().caller().clone();
pallet_hackathon::Pallet::<Runtime, ()>::create_course(
  RawOrigin::Signed(caller).into(),
  course_id,
  open,
  required_skills,
  gained_skills,
  credential_description,
)?;
```

But that results in this error:

```
the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:  <RuntimeOrigin as From<OriginCaller>>  <RuntimeOrigin as From<RawOrigin<<Runtime as SysConfig>::AccountId>>>  <RuntimeOrigin as From<std::option::Option<<Runtime as SysConfig>::AccountId>>>required for `RawOrigin<Origin<<E as Ext>::T>>` to implement `Into<RuntimeOrigin>`
```

What am I doing wrong?